# Account Balances Not Updating When Interacting with Smart Contract on Private OpenEthereum Network

Tags: contract-development, transactions, private-blockchain, openethereum

**Context:**

I have set up a private Ethereum network using OpenEthereum, configured with four nodes: a validator node, two non-validator nodes, and an RPC node. This setup is part of a project for a Blockchain Development course. While I can deploy smart contracts and perform manual transactions without issues, I encounter problems when interacting with deployed smart contracts through a script.

**Network Configuration:**

I have used .toml configuration files for each node. Below are the configurations for the nodes:

non-validator-node-1.toml

```
[parity]
chain = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json"
base_path = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/non-validator-node-1/"
[network]
port = 30300
discovery = true

bootnodes = [
    "enode://f61c72e21a3f299131955cc01c7c03e26e93c46a638861a78fc352c2968ae5b9b572bf8c3288fd544efee1a35d554847b62a2f123aacae216d5102b93cf467db@172.24.0.5:30300",
    "enode://865b22929f5b3bbb60178f8eb256c9bf1ff9438f61ce5a96a0c855884cb08fc16f10fd294b2e12a3388c51f6ce6ce0af91164777033425d05139e6c6a162fdf6@172.24.0.2:30301",
    "enode://ad61c10a75c7804263d1cb6446cbdbff0d6a4037ca68736c5357cbb322b80f4c8b10040018252ac2a1eaae590a62e8e156ec04f42748ee6cca873806e55b2749@172.24.0.3:30302",
    "enode://e2bf6944e55c92e9e990e2160c4a55878638a9812bfd2206a27bb0a955358ab278a8da8270f0f0760414617d9e790bf3e75ab88e6dc6004bf1564482d8d394ea@172.24.0.4:30303"
]

[rpc]
port = 8540
interface = "0.0.0.0"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[websockets]
port = 8450
[account]
password = ["/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/non-validator-node-1/node.pwds"]
unlock = ["0x03ef81396202cb0c7ee5594fad6aab5b4ce6337a"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x03ef81396202cb0c7ee5594fad6aab5b4ce6337a"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

non-validator-node-2.toml

```
[parity]
chain = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json"
base_path = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/non-validator-node-2/"
[network]
port = 30301
discovery = true

bootnodes = [
    "enode://f61c72e21a3f299131955cc01c7c03e26e93c46a638861a78fc352c2968ae5b9b572bf8c3288fd544efee1a35d554847b62a2f123aacae216d5102b93cf467db@172.24.0.5:30300",
    "enode://865b22929f5b3bbb60178f8eb256c9bf1ff9438f61ce5a96a0c855884cb08fc16f10fd294b2e12a3388c51f6ce6ce0af91164777033425d05139e6c6a162fdf6@172.24.0.2:30301",
    "enode://ad61c10a75c7804263d1cb6446cbdbff0d6a4037ca68736c5357cbb322b80f4c8b10040018252ac2a1eaae590a62e8e156ec04f42748ee6cca873806e55b2749@172.24.0.3:30302",
    "enode://e2bf6944e55c92e9e990e2160c4a55878638a9812bfd2206a27bb0a955358ab278a8da8270f0f0760414617d9e790bf3e75ab88e6dc6004bf1564482d8d394ea@172.24.0.4:30303"
]

[rpc]
port = 8541
interface = "0.0.0.0"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[websockets]
port = 8451
[account]
password = ["/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/non-validator-node-2/node.pwds"]
unlock = ["0xdef8f49574a74f53ae4152350bad6bb3b9c7ee8c"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0xdef8f49574a74f53ae4152350bad6bb3b9c7ee8c"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

rpc-node.toml

```
[parity]
chain = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json"
base_path = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/rpc-node/"
[network]
port = 30302
discovery = true

bootnodes = [
    "enode://f61c72e21a3f299131955cc01c7c03e26e93c46a638861a78fc352c2968ae5b9b572bf8c3288fd544efee1a35d554847b62a2f123aacae216d5102b93cf467db@172.24.0.5:30300",
    "enode://865b22929f5b3bbb60178f8eb256c9bf1ff9438f61ce5a96a0c855884cb08fc16f10fd294b2e12a3388c51f6ce6ce0af91164777033425d05139e6c6a162fdf6@172.24.0.2:30301",
    "enode://ad61c10a75c7804263d1cb6446cbdbff0d6a4037ca68736c5357cbb322b80f4c8b10040018252ac2a1eaae590a62e8e156ec04f42748ee6cca873806e55b2749@172.24.0.3:30302",
    "enode://e2bf6944e55c92e9e990e2160c4a55878638a9812bfd2206a27bb0a955358ab278a8da8270f0f0760414617d9e790bf3e75ab88e6dc6004bf1564482d8d394ea@172.24.0.4:30303"
]

[rpc]
port = 8542
interface = "0.0.0.0"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[websockets]
port = 8452
[account]
password = ["/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/rpc-node/node.pwds"]
unlock = ["0x058a43d4a846d193202f151768d64ac92c9f3e8a"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x058a43d4a846d193202f151768d64ac92c9f3e8a"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

validator-node.toml

```
[parity]
chain = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json"
base_path = "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/validator-node/"
[network]
port = 30303
discovery = true

bootnodes = [
    "enode://f61c72e21a3f299131955cc01c7c03e26e93c46a638861a78fc352c2968ae5b9b572bf8c3288fd544efee1a35d554847b62a2f123aacae216d5102b93cf467db@172.24.0.5:30300",
    "enode://865b22929f5b3bbb60178f8eb256c9bf1ff9438f61ce5a96a0c855884cb08fc16f10fd294b2e12a3388c51f6ce6ce0af91164777033425d05139e6c6a162fdf6@172.24.0.2:30301",
    "enode://ad61c10a75c7804263d1cb6446cbdbff0d6a4037ca68736c5357cbb322b80f4c8b10040018252ac2a1eaae590a62e8e156ec04f42748ee6cca873806e55b2749@172.24.0.3:30302",
    "enode://e2bf6944e55c92e9e990e2160c4a55878638a9812bfd2206a27bb0a955358ab278a8da8270f0f0760414617d9e790bf3e75ab88e6dc6004bf1564482d8d394ea@172.24.0.4:30303"
]

[rpc]
port = 8543
interface = "0.0.0.0"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[websockets]
port = 8453
[account]
password = ["/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/validator-node/node.pwds"]
unlock = ["0xb8a436ad7411fd199e5191422a41d4cce3b58c7b"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0xb8a436ad7411fd199e5191422a41d4cce3b58c7b"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  non-validator-node-1:
    image: openethereum/openethereum:latest
    volumes:
      - ./non-validator-node-1.toml:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/non-validator-node-1.toml
      - ./genesis.json:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json
      - ./nodes/non-validator-node-1:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/non-validator-node-1
    command: ["--config", "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/non-validator-node-1.toml"]
    ports:
      - "30300:30300"
      - "8540:8540"
      - "8450:8450"
    networks:
      private-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.5

  non-validator-node-2:
    image: openethereum/openethereum:latest
    volumes:
      - ./non-validator-node-2.toml:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/non-validator-node-2.toml
      - ./genesis.json:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json
      - ./nodes/non-validator-node-2:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/non-validator-node-2
    command: ["--config", "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/non-validator-node-2.toml"]
    ports:
      - "30301:30301"
      - "8541:8541"
      - "8451:8451"
    networks:
      private-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.2

  rpc-node:
    image: openethereum/openethereum:latest
    volumes:
      - ./rpc-node.toml:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/rpc-node.toml
      - ./genesis.json:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json
      - ./nodes/rpc-node:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/rpc-node
    command: ["--config", "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/rpc-node.toml"]
    ports:
      - "30302:30302"
      - "8542:8542"
      - "8452:8452"
    networks:
      private-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.3

  validator-node:
    image: openethereum/openethereum:latest
    volumes:
      - ./validator-node.toml:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/validator-node.toml
      - ./genesis.json:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/genesis.json
      - ./nodes/validator-node:/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/nodes/validator-node
    command: ["--config", "/home/martin/tokio-school/vacante-1/validator-node.toml"]
    ports:
      - "30303:30303"
      - "8543:8543"
      - "8453:8453"
    networks:
      private-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.4


networks:
  private-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.24.0.0/16
```

genesis.json

```
{
    "name": "tokio-school",
    "engine": {
        "authorityRound": {
            "params": {
                "stepDuration": "5",
                "validators": {
                    "list": ["0xb8a436ad7411fd199e5191422a41d4cce3b58c7b"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "params": {
        "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
        "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
        "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
        "networkID": "20240",
        "eip155Transition": 0,
        "validateChainIdTransition": 0,
        "eip140Transition": 0,
        "eip211Transition": 0,
        "eip214Transition": 0,
        "eip658Transition": 0
    },
    "genesis": {
        "seal": {
            "authorityRound": {
                "step": "0x0",
                "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            }
        },
        "difficulty": "0x20000",
        "gasLimit": "0x9502F900"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
            "balance": "1",
            "builtin": {
                "name": "ecrecover",
                "pricing": {
                    "linear": {
                        "base": 3000,
                        "word": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "0x03ef81396202cb0c7ee5594fad6aab5b4ce6337a": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" },
        "0xdef8f49574a74f53ae4152350bad6bb3b9c7ee8c": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" },
        "0x058a43d4a846d193202f151768d64ac92c9f3e8a": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" },
        "0xb8a436ad7411fd199e5191422a41d4cce3b58c7b": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" },
        "0x3EF149b926BA083640652048720B3F963663bd08": {
            "balance": "100000000000000000000",
            "code": "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",
            "storage": {},
            "nonce": "0x0"
        }
    }
}
```

**Smart Contract:**

EtherTransfer.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract EtherTransfer {
    address public owner;

    // Define events to be emitted
    event EtherReceivedEvent(address indexed _from, uint256 _amount);
    event EtherSendEvent(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _amount);
    event InsufficientBalance(uint256 requestedAmount, uint256 contractBalance);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // Modified fallback function to receive Ether and emit an event
    receive() external payable {
        emit EtherReceivedEvent(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    // Modified sendEther function with additional logging
    function sendEther(address payable _to, uint256 _amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can send Ether");

        uint256 contractBalance = address(this).balance;
        if (contractBalance < _amount) {
            emit InsufficientBalance(_amount, contractBalance);
            return;
        }

        _to.transfer(_amount);
        emit EtherSendEvent(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

When I interact with the deployed EtherTransfer contract using a script, the account balances do not update as expected. This issue occurs despite successful contract deployment and manual transactions.

Here is the script that I am using to (try) to interact with it:

transfer.js

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs');

const web3 = new Web3('http://172.24.0.3:8542');
const contractAddress = '0x3EF149b926BA083640652048720B3F963663bd08'; // Update with new contract address after redeployment
const contractABI = require('../../artifacts/contracts/EtherTransfer.sol/EtherTransfer.json').abi;

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

const senderAccount = '0x03ef81396202cb0c7ee5594fad6aab5b4ce6337a';
const privateKey = '0xbaf04ffb7b5ce50878a488391c20095373e8df28bafd912a1da9ee22f14b0009';
const recipient = '0xdef8f49574a74f53ae4152350bad6bb3b9c7ee8c';
const amount = web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether');

async function sendEther() {
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAccount);
    const tx = {
        to: contractAddress,
        data: contract.methods.sendEther(recipient, amount).encodeABI(),
        gas: 300000,
        nonce: nonce,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')
    };

    try {
        const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
        console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in transaction:', error);
    }
}

sendEther().catch(console.error);
```

Results when executing:

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x03ef81396202cb0c7ee5594fad6aab5b4ce6337a", "latest"],"id": 1}' -H "Content-Type: application/j
son" -X POST localhost:8540
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x21e1707e5e2ac288800","id":1}

curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xdef8f49574a74f53ae4152350bad6bb3b9c7ee8c", "latest"],"id": 2}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8541
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x21e1e0a9a23cade0000","id":2}

node transfer.js
Transaction receipt: {
  blockHash: '0x55544a99fec0df9f3336b99a9518a713a6f10908aad3fcfb73c5371c4b47a001',
  blockNumber: 67,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 28745,
  effectiveGasPrice: 20000000000,
  from: '0x03ef81396202cb0c7ee5594fad6aab5b4ce6337a',
  gasUsed: 28745,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  status: true,
  to: '0x3ef149b926ba083640652048720b3f963663bd08',
  transactionHash: '0x4949f08f90b16a83080bd07311f19e32b4c39d88b1486914bd94fc3bdf19472a',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  type: '0x0'
}

curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x03ef81396202cb0c7ee5594fad6aab5b4ce6337a", "latest"],"id": 1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x21e15a1178f19884000","id":1}

curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xdef8f49574a74f53ae4152350bad6bb3b9c7ee8c", "latest"],"id": 2}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8541
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x21e1e0a9a23cade0000","id":2}
```

**Questions:**

1. What could cause account balances not to update when interacting with a smart contract in a private OpenEthereum network?
2. Are there specific configurations in OpenEthereum that I should check or adjust?
3. Any insights or best practices for troubleshooting smart contract interactions in this setup would be highly appreciated.

**Additional Note:**

I'm relatively new to blockchain development and working with OpenEthereum, so there might be something fundamental that I'm overlooking. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions from more experienced members of the community.